# c# notify data shows in console, but does not in application

Tags: c#, wpf, postgresql

Hello I need a little help I send notify message to my c# app, then I get messege it appears on the console but it does not if I try to make it label content on app window here is the code:

```
using (var conn = new NpgsqlConnection("Server=xxxxx"))
        {
            conn.Notification += OnNotification;
            conn.Open();
            using (var command = new NpgsqlCommand("listen mymessage;", conn))
            {
                command.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
            mymessage  = Console.ReadLine();

        };
        Console.WriteLine(mymessage);
    }

    public void OnNotification(object sender, NpgsqlNotificationEventArgs e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(e.AdditionalInformation);
        label1.Content = e.AdditionalInformation;
    }
```

console writeline works but label1.content does not change

Comment: What type is label1?

Comment: most likely it's a WPF label

Comment: What do you mean type? It is string.

Comment: Yes it is wpf type. Edited.

Comment: AFAIK, console is not available in WPF, where do you see output from ` Console.WriteLine`?

Comment: Console.WriteLine(e.AdditionalInformation); gives me message sent from postgresql pg_notify

Comment: I change project properties from windows app to console to see rezult

Comment: Why not print it on a label or any other message box sort or log somewhere? This is a weird way of debugging.

Comment: Well it is my way, but I looking for help how to print it on my label1.contet.

Comment: @Bensinaspa, just use `Debug.WriteLine` and the output will be printed in Output window (under Debug -> Windows -> Output). Maybe last iteration of calling `Notification` has empty `AdditionalInformation` property and it clears label?

Comment: here is debug log: 
    The thread '<No Name>' (0x5d0) has exited with code 0 (0x0).

Comment: @Bensinaspa, no, I meant change all your `Console.WriteLine` to `Debug.WriteLine`. and do not change project properties. okay try to do this: `label1.Content = label1.Content + e.AdditionalInformation;`

Comment: @Ben Sin Aspa, you may have a problem because the label update doesn't happen on the GUI thread. So check with a breakpoint you are on the GUI thread when notification happens (Debug/Windows/Threads), if not, add this code : label1.Dispatcher.Invoke( ()=>{ label1.Content=e.AdditionalInformation; }); Regards